# Looking for the name of a novel involving blobs

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I'm trying to remember the name of a novel that involved the explorers meeting an alien species that was basically large blobs in an ocean-like environment. I thought perhaps it was written by Spider Robinson but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably the [Rocheworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocheworld) series (original title *Flight of the Dragonfly*) by [Robert L. Forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_L._Forward). The blob creatures are the "flouwen". From the Wikipedia article about the first book in the series:

> Flouwen are blob-like happy-go-lucky aliens that spend their days
> surfing waves and working on difficult mathematical problems.
>
> Flouwen appear to be giant, colored jellyfish-like entities in the
> ammonia oceans of Eau. They look like colored blobs of jelly, but they
> can change their shape at will. They are highly intelligent, sexless,
> and do not appear to physically age.

Another detail that may help identify the story: The astronauts arrive by non-relativistic travel after forty years; the ship is powered by a "solar" sail pushed by an array of very powerful lasers from our solar system. They were given a drug during their journey that reversibly slows their aging, with the unavoidable but reversible side effect of making them mentally childlike.

Comment: Wow I can't believe how quickly someone answered that. That's indeed the story that I was looking for. 
I'd forgotten about the Christmas bush AI in there as well. I thought that was the coolest thing ever when I was a kid. Thank you so much!